# Save the internal state of each kernel and start the computation again later

Tags: parallelization

I use ParallelEvaluate[], inside that is a lengthy code, many variables are calculated and updated may times, lets say a=..., b=..., c=...

Lets say I want to stop calculation once, and start calculation again, from the state I stopped the calculation. One way to do this is, the results obtained in each Kernel can be saved by a>>>"xxx.m", b..."xxx.m" when the calculation is stopped, and when restarting we may do stuff like imported=Import["xxx.m",All][[2,1]], a=imported[[1]], b=imported[[2]], ...

but the problem is, when we have so many variables, doing the above is kind of difficult, I may forget to save some variable etc.

Does someone know a better way of doing the above? That is, saving and reloading the internal state of each Kernel in one go.

Comment: See [How to checkpoint computations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59542/27951) and [Are there methods to serialize and deserialize large calculation runs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72192/27951).

Comment: You may also find this overview of methods to save definitions useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/27951